# Magento 2 Install error: "There is no such engine:"

Tags: magento2, error, magento2.2, magento2-enterprise

I tried to install Magento 2.2 EE on my local with MySQL 5.7.21 and PHP 7. On the command "bin/magento setup:install" it starts to populate the database until a point when it crashes with the following error:

```
   Progress: 434 / 801]
   Module 'Magento_CatalogSearch':
   Installing data...

       [LogicException]
       There is no such engine:
```

That's all I got. I tried to modify the table 'core_config_data' where path is 'catalog/search/engine' to 'mysql', realised that it wasn't even there, had to add it manually, but it didn't work at all, at the "bin/magento setup:upgrade" it also crashes at Magento_CatalogSearch with the same error "There is no such engine:".

Any ideas how can I get rid of this error?

Comment: which version of magento are you using ( i.e CE or EE ) ?

Comment: Is this Magento Commerce ?

Comment: @Naveed it is Magento 2 EE

Comment: @vitoriodachef it is Magento 2 EE

Comment: check db engine in magento.yaml / services.yaml if it is mysql or sloar/elastic search.

Comment: Do you have rabbitmq installed ? Magento Commerce formerly known as Enterprise required rabbitMq installed and configured prior to installing Magento

Answer (score 1):

Try with the below 3 steps:

1. Ignore the Magento_CatalogSearch installation during the first time

Go to app/etc/config.php and disable this module, Search for Magento_CatalogSearch and change 1 to 0.

2. Run this SQL query after successful installation or can be done in background

> UPDATE core_config_data set value = 'mysql' where
>   path='catalog/search/engine';

3. After installation is successful, Run the below CLI command to upgrade, flush the cache and reindex

> php -f bin/magento setup:upgrade php -f bin/magento cache:flush php -f
>   bin/magento indexer:reindex

Comment: @E.Mayer: Did you try this solution? Did you get chance to check the MySql log?

Answer (score 0):

You set up a catalog search engine that does not exist at '`catalog/search/engine`' in your config.
See: `app/code/Magento/CatalogSearch/Model/ResourceModel/EngineProvider.php`

So you probably configured a search engine you did not install.

Comment: mysql was the engine, it's installed.

Comment: I have never installed a search engine. But did you check if the setup string are correct? Did you set that manually or via dropdown in the backend?

Answer (score 0):

Searching for the log message:

```
/**
 * Get engine singleton
 *
 * @return EngineInterface
 */
public function get()
{
    if (!$this->engine) {
        $currentEngine = $this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::CONFIG_ENGINE_PATH, ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
        if (!isset($this->enginePool[$currentEngine])) {
            throw new \LogicException(
                'There is no such engine: ' . $currentEngine
            );
        }
        $engineClassName = $this->enginePool[$currentEngine];
...
```

Further up in the class there is a config constant: `const CONFIG_ENGINE_PATH = 'catalog/search/engine';` Which I would look into what it is set to, most likely the search engine configured like elasticsearch is set but not available.

- https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/9c14af7a97bcf338662de365d2613c7ca9dbf8c6/app/code/Magento/CatalogSearch/Model/ResourceModel/EngineProvider.php#L70

Also was this an upgrade from 1.x?